# Remove permissions on list item change in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, permissions, survey-list

Is there any chance I can remove survey permissions on List item change?
Can i somehow set workflow on list item change to remove survey permissions?

Answer (score 1):

What are you actually trying to accomplish (i.e. the reason behind changing the permissions)?  detailing the actual "requirement" will net you a better answer. But I will give you some possible routes that may solve different problems.

OOTB with SP Designer the answer is no.

If you all you want to do is limit the number of times a survey can be submitted than that can be set in the survey itself.

You could use Visual Studio can create a new action that does that or code a workflow directly in VS to accomplish this, because it requires the use of the API.

Additionally you could use InfoPath web forms (if you have enterprise edition CALs) and create your own survey.  You can use a combination of tracking columns and forms to show / hide the information you want. If you don't have InfoPath Webforms available, you can still achieve similar results with custom list pages and JavaScript, but it is a bit more work.

I'm assuming as well that all your users are authenticated and not anonymous. You have to make some farm level changes to allow Anon. users access to submit InfoPath forms.